# sql python The value entered in the table is set first, the second is null

Tags: python, sql, bots, telegram

i create table

```
def sql_table_strategy():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('strategy.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS strategy"
                   "(stra TEXT NOT NULL,"
                   "probability TEXT NOT NULL,"
                   " chat_id INTEGER UNIQUE)")
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

integraite strategy

```
def strategy_add(stra, ChatID):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('strategy.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    val = (stra, ChatID)
    sql = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO strategy (stra,chat_id) VALUES (?,?)"
    cursor.execute(sql, val)
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

add probability

```
def pr_add(probability, ChatID):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('strategy.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    val = (probability,ChatID)
    sql = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO strategy (probability,chat_id) VALUES (?,?)"
    cursor.execute(sql, val)
    conn.close()
    conn.close()
```

when I add the first strategy and then I add probability but in Columns probability is null 
[image]

Comment: you cant insert a value in an existing row using insert. if you want to change an existing column use update https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for your problem.

```
def pr_add(probability, ChatID):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('strategy.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    val = (probability,ChatID)
    sql = "UPDATE strategy SET probability = ? WHERE chat_id = ?"   --Change is here
    cursor.execute(sql, val)
    conn.close()
    conn.close()
```